# Extract timestamp from row of data

Tags: java

I have an input csv file like:

> 0,Mike,2015-12-04 21:56:32
>   1,Raj,2015-12-04 11:53:29

I want to extract the timestamp from the file. What is the easiest way to do it in Java.

Comment: match the length of default timestamp with the length between the delimiters. But it may be faulty in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
while(reader.hasNext()) {
    String csvString = reader.nextLine();
    String[] splits = csvString.split(",");
    System.out.println("Record: " + splits[0] + " Timestamp: " + splits[2]);
}
```

Output:

```
Record: 0 Timestamp: 2015-12-04 21:56:32
Record: 1 Timestamp: 2015-12-04 11:53:29
```

Comment: I would be careful to assume that the timestamp doesn't contain commas.  We have no guarantees that we won't eventually find one with a comma.  Not a very robust solution.  Ideally you should grab anything following the 2nd comma for each line.

Comment: But if i want  to have the both Timestamps

Comment: @Abdelhak Sorry, I missed that there are two entries because of formatting issues. Assuming that the file is being read line-by-line, I updated the solution. Thank You

Comment: Now it's more better

Comment: Is there any way to not to hard code the position 2. It could be possible that timestamp is present at other locations.

Comment: You can iterate through the columns and try parsing the date, if it gives you error then continue with the next column and if it get parsed successfully then stop. Although, I'm not sure whether it is a good way of doing it.

Comment: Also, I am sorry i forgot to mention. Both the lines i mentioned in the question are in byte datatype.